# Search data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2005, search

I'm basically making a web site using VS2008 and SQL Server 2005 which initiates with a login page. Now I want to authenticate the `LoginID` and the `Password` entered by the user. This authentication will take place once the system has found the ID and Password from the database table. Once found, I want to check whether what kind of user it is i.e. `Admin` or `Customer`. If the user is admin, then the page should be redirected to `abc.aspx` otherwise `cde.aspx`.

My front-end for LoginPage is:

```
<tr>
<td class="style11"> Login </td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Width="300px" CssClass="Textbox1"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="style11"> Password </td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="300px" CssClass="Textbox1"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="btn1"
                    Text="Submit" />
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" CssClass="btn1"
                    Text="Cancel" />
</td>
</tr>
```

And my backend code is:

```
//CODE 1
SqlDataSource sds = new SqlDataSource();
sds.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Gen_LicConnectionString3"].ToString();
sds.SelectParameters.Add("LoginID", TypeCode.String, this.txtUserName.Text);
sds.SelectParameters.Add("Password", TypeCode.String, this.txtPassword.Text);
sds.SelectCommand = "SELECT User_Type FROM [User_Details] WHERE [LoginID]=@LoginID AND [Password]=@Password";

    if (//Some Condition) //<-- Here I want to check the condition whether the User_Type is 'Admin' or 'Customer'
    {
        Response.Redirect("Lic_Gen.aspx"); //<-- If Admin
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Cust_Page.aspx"); //<-- If Customer
    }


//CODE 2
//string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Gen_LicConnectionString3"].ConnectionString;
    //string selectSQL = "SELECT User_Type FROM User_Details WHERE [LoginID]=@LoginID AND [Password] = @Password";
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    //SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    //DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //if (cmd.Equals(1))
    //{
    //    Response.Redirect("Lic_Gen.aspx");
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    Response.Redirect("Cust_Page.aspx");
    //}
```

Comment: whatever the user type be - whether admin or customer - the page either way gets redirected to the `Cust_Page`

Comment: Have you looked at the ASP.Net membership model? It does this pretty much out of the box...also, please - PLEASE - do not store passwords in plain text. You should hash them, using a secure hashing algorithm and a salt value.

Comment: Also this can cause Sql injection.

Comment: How does this  `if (dv.Count == 0) ` tell you that the user is an Admin ?

Comment: @NevilleK : Absolutely, I'll keep that in mind when it comes to passwords. And regarding membership model. I'll just check into that.

Comment: @ryadavilli: Honestly, I'm still trying. I tried another version of it. using `sqlcommand` but still I'm not getting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest method without the use membership models. This is a simple method which uses datareader.

```
    SqlDataReader sdrDatanew = null;
    string strnew;
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Gen_LicConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connew = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connew.Open();
    strnew = "select User_Type from User_Details where User_Type='" + ddlUserSel.SelectedItem.Value + "' AND LoginID = '" + txtUserName.Text + "' AND Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand sqlCommnew = new SqlCommand(strnew, connew);
    sdrDatanew = sqlCommnew.ExecuteReader();

    int userType = 0;

    if (sdrDatanew.HasRows)
    {
        if (sdrDatanew.Read())
        {
            userType = Convert.ToInt32(sdrDatanew["User_Type"].ToString());
        }
    }

    switch (userType)
    {
        case 0:
            Response.Redirect("Lic_Gen.aspx");
            break;
        case 1:
            Response.Redirect("Cust_Page.aspx");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid User/Password");
            Console.ReadLine();
            break;
    }

    connew.Close();
```