# Store Value from sql Command and compare it with value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlcommand

This is with reference to my previous question:

[Search data in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720193/search-data-in-database)

I have used the following code to execute my query. But I'm having issues for storing the value from the command and then use that result to compare the value.

This is my code:

```
SqlDataReader sdrDatanew = null;
string strnew;
string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Gen_LicConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connew = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connew.Open();
strnew = "select User_Type from User_Details where User_Type='" + ddlUserSel.SelectedItem.Value + "' AND LoginID = '" + txtUserName.Text + "' AND Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
SqlCommand sqlCommnew = new SqlCommand(strnew, connew);
sdrDatanew = sqlCommnew.ExecuteReader();
if (sdrDatanew.HasRows)
  {
     if (sdrDatanew.Read())
      {
          //Here I want to store the result from the sqlcommand in a variable
      }
  }

    switch (//Here I want to use the variable in a switch case) //<---
    {
        case 0:
            Response.Redirect("Lic_Gen.aspx");
            break;
        case 1:
            Response.Redirect("Cust_Page.aspx");
            break;
    }

    connew.Close();
```

Comment: I'm not getting how to store the result from the sqlcommand to a variable. Like whatever result i'm getting from the sql query, I want the value to be stored and then I can use that variable in a switch case.

Comment: because strnew is storing the query. not the result. how do i store the result? and how do i use it in the switch case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

and more specifically at the line

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),reader.GetString(1));
```

at any of the get functions

for eg

[SqlDataReader.GetString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  and [SqlDataReader.GetInt32 Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

so you could try something like

```
int userType = 0;
if (sdrDatanew.HasRows)
{
    if (sdrDatanew.Read())
    {
        userType = sdrDatanew.GetInt32(0); //something like this
    }
}

switch (userType) //something like this
{
    case 0:
        Response.Redirect("Lic_Gen.aspx");
        break;
    case 1:
        Response.Redirect("Cust_Page.aspx");
        break;
}
```

Comment: If I apply a breakpoint at int userType = 0, now the if statement is turning out to be false.

Comment: now it's giving me an error: `specified cast not valid` at `userType = sdrDatanew.GetInt32(0)` statement

Comment: What is the type of User_Type in the database? and what is the type suppose to be in C#?

Comment: It's okay. Had to covert it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `sdrDatanew.GetInt32(0)` method and use `parameterized` sql statement.

```
using(SqlConnection connew = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
  strnew = @"select User_Type from User_Details where User_Type=@usertype 
             AND LoginID=@loginid AND Password = @password";
  using(SqlCommand sqlCommnew = new SqlCommand(strnew, connew))
   {
     sqlCommnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype",ddlUserSel.SelectedItem.Value);
     sqlCommnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginid",txtUserName.Text);
     sqlCommnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",txtPassword.Text);

     connew.Open();
     sdrDatanew = sqlCommnew.ExecuteReader();

     int userType=-1;
     if(sdrDatanew.Read())
        userType=sdrDatanew.GetInt32(0);

     switch (userType)
      {
       case 0:
           Response.Redirect("Lic_Gen.aspx");
           break;
       case 1:
           Response.Redirect("Cust_Page.aspx");
           break;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Declare your variables before the line

```
if (sdrDatanew.HasRows)
```

And store the value where you want to. You will be able to use the variable where you have written switch case.

//This will store the value of first column in the row.

```
var row=((IDataRecord) (sdrDatanew))[0];
```

Comment: That's what I'm not getting. How do i store the result? from the query?

Comment: Added the line to show how can we read column values from reader.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to get the result try this code

```
while (sdrDatanew.Read()) {
String userDetails = sdrDatanew("User_Details").ToString;

}
```

I cant understand what are you doing. Do you want to get the result and what is the result is it just a string or a collection of strings?

Answer (score 0):

try the following instead:

```
 string value = string.Empty
 if (sdrDatanew.HasRows)
 {
     while (sdrDatanew.Read())
     {
          value= results[0].ToString();
     }
 }
```

or since it is just one column you selecting the following:

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'column' from 'table' WHERE 'column' ='criteria' ";

                    string value = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }
```